# Python (x,y) MatplotLib Widget Initialisation

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pythonxy

I'm trying to get started with Python(x,y) and its MatplotlibWidget for PyQt. I've got the widget plopped in my prospective GUI with QTDesigner and have converted the .ui to .py, but I'm lost on what to do for a meaningful matplotlibwidget.py file.

If anyone could advise on how to get started or point me in the direction of a good source, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: "I'm lost on what to do for a meaningful matplotlibwidget.py file" I'm lost too. What do you want to achieve? Integrate matplotlibwidget in QtDesigner or something else?

Comment: I would suggest as a first step not to use the MatplotlibWidget but create a QT application by hand and embed matplotlib. There are some examples on the matplotlib page and many others even here on SO about that. Once that is working and you understood how it works, it will be pretty obvious how to use the Widgets from QT designer.